visual studio code, i have managed to change all the colours but one
with love2d in visual studio . when i type love.graphics.rectangle() for example , i would like to change the graphics word to a different colour i have changed everything but i can not find what this is in the setting.json
tried looking online i have changed countless {
"scope": "tried every thing i could think of",
"settings": {
"fontStyle": "",
"foreground":"#e9792e"
}
},

what does the TextMate Scope inspector give the word graphics for scope

Thank you with what you said, i used The "Developer: Inspect editor tokens and scopes" command so helpful , thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

From the comment that was left, i opened the command pallet type >inspect  select  The "Developer: Inspect editor tokens and scopes" command just click on any syntax you want to change and you should get the information you need to use in Edit in settings.json
